# Insert query returns error : SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple enough insert query but i have no idea why it is returning an error. i can see the error comes from the row Birthay, if i remove it the insert is done ok.
My query:

```
INSERT
INTO DATA_INDIVID
 (
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TYPE,
ACCOUNT_STATUS,
FIRST_NAME,
MIDDLE_NAME,
LAST_NAME,
COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE,
TAX_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER,
ADDRESS,
To_Date (BIRTHDAY) BIRTH
 )
 VALUES
(
'44444',
'11111',
'Close',
'LEC',
'xxxx',
'yyyyy',
'GR',
'11111111111',
'test/test/test 1234',
'1978-06-24'
 );
```

it is returning this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
 01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `To_Date (BIRTHDAY) BIRTH` isn't a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the column name in the list of columns and a `DATE` literal in the `VALUES` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO DATA_INDIVID
(
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER_TYPE,
  ACCOUNT_STATUS,
  FIRST_NAME,
  MIDDLE_NAME,
  LAST_NAME,
  COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE,
  TAX_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER,
  ADDRESS,
  BIRTHDAY
) VALUES (
  '44444',
  '11111',
  'Close',
  'LEC',
  'xxxx',
  'yyyyy',
  'GR',
  '11111111111',
  'test/test/test 1234',
  DATE '1978-06-24'
);
```

You could also use:

```sql
TO_DATE( '1978-06-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
```

in the values clause.

Answer (score 0):

In an insert statement specify a list of database columns after the table name. Those need to map to the table columns. In the `values` section you can apply format masks like `TO_DATE`. Not sure if your column is BIRTH or BIRTHDAY - I assumed the latter - change it to the actual column name if it is wrong:

```
INSERT
INTO DATA_INDIVID
 (
...
ADDRESS,
BIRTHDAY
 )
 VALUES
(
...
'test/test/test 1234',
TO_DATE('1978-06-24','YYYY-MM-DD')
 );
```